One of my colleague's largest publication seems to be plagiarized/purely reproductive-What to do?
This year, a post-doc joined our research group, his main publication is a Nature Communications paper with 21 authors in total (solid state physics).
As his and my work have quite some overlap, I began to notice that out of the 15 subfigures in the paper, 12 are straight up reproductions of work published between 6-70 years before they published their paper. The information they convey, even the layout and design of the subfigures can all be found in other publications.
There are only two subfigures which I haven't yet found in the wider literature. These two subfigures are heavily derivative of the other figures in the paper.
As is usual in our field, there is not much said in the text that isn't somehow in the figures, so the text itself is also like this.
For 11 out of 15 subfigures, they do at least cite some sources, but these subfigures and the information therein are so commonplace in the field, that no claim to novelty can be based on these figures.
The other four subfigures are a bit more complicated. As I mentioned two are derivative, the other two have been published years before his paper, but he conveniently omits citing their work. Even though the mechanism and main conclusion he brings in his paper were already mentioned in these two works. I do believe he actually performed these measurements.
I wonder what am I to do with this?

Do I tell this to my boss?

Do I inform my institute?

Should something like this be retracted?

Do I confront him?


Personally, I am shocked, that 21 people, including some big names can get together and publish something like this. I am also deeply worried of picking fights and I am not sure my superiors would like to hear about my finding. (None of my direct superiors are part of the 21 co-authors).

More plagiarism than derivation would you say?

The structure of his paper is basically this 11 pictures are pure and utter reproduction that he needs to establish that he indeed has the material he wants to have (he does this in a very redundant and verbose way).  The methods  of verification are very well known. Then we have the grand finale of two subfigures, which are plagiarized, then from one of the two plagiarzed pictures he derives two additional subfigures. However if you take the plagiarized pictures away basically nothing of substanceis left in my opinion in the picture.

(1) What is your position in the group? (2) You write that "these subfigures and the information therein are so common place in the field". That makes me wonder how the paper got published. After all, it needed to demonstrate novelty to the reviewers and editor. Plagiarism is usually a question of re-using material that is uncommon.

Is the prior similar work cited in the paper? It can be perfectly normal that most of a paper is reestablishing results already found to effectively show that you're working with the same material. It might be better to focus on the supposed novel figures that you claim are plagiarized.

Sounds like you’re the watchdog of the group. Have you discussed the matter in any fashion with this new colleague yet?

Are the reviewer comments available? Nature Communications sometimes post them, and they could be useful to read to figure out which parts the reviewers  believed to be novel.

As a remark: You keep on referring to your colleague as if he is the only author of a paper with, by your accounting, 21. Orthogonal to your question, I don't think that's a particularly useful perspective, as I doubt any 1 author constructed the majority of the figures.

Why do you consistently say "he did…" etc. when there are "21 authors in total" involved?

@user176372 Really? In my field I would assume the first author was responsible for all the figures.

I am not the watch dog of the group, it just happens to be he case that we both work on similar thing and ever so often I realize that what ever he wrote I can find in anohter paper from before. I am just getting familiar with the field and know this particular paper quite well. I coincidentally realized this because I know the wider literature and his paper,  but i felt this was so glaring that I couldnt avoid noticing.

To the 21 authors, of course I dont actually know what all these 21 ppl did, even the attribution at the end of the article has some 7 ppl just participating "in discussions of the paper".  After publication, he does clearly make it seem, like this was mostly his work, he goes around and gives talks leaving the impression that the other 20 ppl were just supervising/funding/along for the ride. I think it is save to assume, by the standards of my field, that he was at least a major contributor to each subfigure.

Where is the big "plagiarism"? All you've stated is copied figures. Are they essential to the paper? I'm confused. Is it the case in solid state physics, that figures are part of the "results"?

@Dilworth is there any field where figures aren't part of the results? Figures include graphs, plotted data, images of experimental results etc. In my experience, they are usually there to convey results. The only exception I can think of off the top of my head would be a figure used only to explain the experimental setup, but usually I would expect figures to be showing the data, the results.

@terdon: Yes, pure math, where figures are simply meant to illustrate a proof or a definition. In contrast, results in pure math are theorems.

@terdon, yes I come from math; I never realized a figure (which is normally merely a nice pedagogic illustration in math) would be a part of the "result".

DO NOT contact anyone but the journal, from a burner account, and I fear your description here is already too frank unless you've subtly misdirected a bit (e.g., number of authors) and the question should perhaps be deleted.  The risk/reward calculation is against you.  You have to watch out for your career and research is too small a world to make even one enemy.  There is no possible reward.  There is however risk big or small, which cannot be quantified or known, so it is a bad decision.  Scale the heights of the ivory tower and do more honest work yourself: that must be your revenge.

I would not assume your colleague had anything to do with the figures.
Be very very careful; you can read about the extremely sad story of Ranga Dias who claimed to have discovered room-temperature superconductivity; Dias was not first author of a now retracted infamous paper, and also of this other retracted but apparently had a hand in producing the figures.  Please, read the story to understand how students can be unwitting participants in deceptions.
If you have solid grounds to suspect plagiarism or image manipulation, you should contact the journal. They have the resources to conduct a full investigation, and they would be the last arbiters of the case anyways.

Edit: thanks to the link provided by @anyon, you can read Dias investigation committee report on this mess.  To highlight and reinforce my suggested caution,
here's an excerpt from page 16:

Prior to publication, [Dr. Dias] provided R(T) data to co-authors only in the form of finished figures and not in the form of raw measurement data.

Here's another excerpt from page 19:

In his discussion with the Investigation Committee, [Dr. Dias] assumed responsibility for assembling the data and preparing the figures and manuscript for the Nature 2020 (CSH) Paper.

Please, do not reach hasty conclusions on the origin of figures (or more generally data or text) before you know with certainly who created the figures.  Much better to let the journal handle this: they have the authority to ask for raw data and give the authors a chance to explain any suspicious figures.

The actual investigation report makes for interesting and sad reading for anyone desiring more details https://www.nature.com/magazine-assets/d41586-024-00976-y/26947600

@Anyon wow!  I did not realize the report was publicly available.  Many thanks…

This is a very nice answer!

Note all three links in this answer are paywalled

@BenVoigt  I wish they weren’t but that can’t be helped.

I would advise you against making any outright accusations, or using any words that can be perceived as accusatory in nature and involving subjective judgments, such as “plagiarism” and “purely reproductive”, in connection with your colleague’s paper.
What you can reasonably do is share factual information regarding your findings with your superiors. Unless you are very high up the totem pole, you should not leap to conclusions that involve subjective value judgments about whether someone committed plagiarism or other type of misconduct. If you’re going to report anything, report pure, objectively verifiable facts (“subfigure 2.3 is similar to a subfigure from previously published reference […], which is not cited in the paper”) and let others draw their own conclusions and decide what if any action is appropriate to take.
I can’t advise you on whether it’s a good idea to make such a report. That depends on many things. But, as long as you stick to facts, it does not sound like it would be unreasonable to share your observations with the PI.
Some other things to consider:

There is much more to a paper than figures. What about the actual analysis and other scientific content? Even if all the figures are reused, it’s not clear that this would be plagiarism.

The paper has 21 authors! Is your colleague the first author? If yes, it may make sense to consider him as largely responsible for the figure reuse, but even so, he shares a good part of the responsibility with other authors. If he is not the first author, his culpability even in the case of misconduct would appear quite limited, and in that case, the fact that his “main publication” is as a minor coauthor on a paper with 21 authors should probably be of greater concern to you than the alleged misconduct.

Consider the possibility that, more than being an unethical paper, this paper is simply a bad or mediocre one with a low level of novelty. It wouldn’t be the first time such a thing has been published in a good journal, even by large groups of authors from well-known universities.



Complete aside: the holiest part of a totem pole is the base. :-)

Thanks. I dont want to reveal the actual paper here, in the whole text(its really not long maybe 2-3 pages inclduing the figures and headline) there is I would say 2-3paragraphs which are novel (at least I havent found them in some other paper yet). Mainly these present an analysis of data that someone else already pubilshed(which they fail to mention),  however their analysis  in the 2-3 paragraphs has a different  focus then the one published before.  He is the first author, and I have seen him make a big show about this work in the past, suggesting he really claims this for himself.

Reach out to your PI or other big name of your institute. Ask her/him, that you do not see the novelty of the paper if s/he can help you understand this. You must make it sound as honest curiosity, why this deserves to be published in such a high-ranked journal. Don't make accusations.
In the best case, you learn something, you did not get from reading the paper yourself. If your feeling is right, your peer starts wondering how this was ever published. Do not push further, let it go and try to write papers with more scientific value.

PubPeer.com is intended to be an effective tool for handling situations like this.  Post there, anonymously, if the journal's editors are not responsive.

I would be very cautious about making official charges in any venue. Not everyone will make the same judgement about such things. There are a lot of considerations, including whether there are creative elements in the images or not. This affects both plagiarism and copyright. There is also the question about what license(s) might apply to the figures, since the publication itself is open access.
But, I think it would be appropriate to have a quiet word with them, face to face, raising the issues. "These seem to be copies...." Maybe they can give you a good explanation of why it was appropriate, if, indeed, it is.
But "confront" may imply the wrong attitude going in. Among other things, it would probably negate the possibility of any cooperative relationship in the future.
Maybe a retraction or correction is needed, but get full information first, including that provided by the author(s).
